# Why is there a unique measure $\mu$ s.t. $\mu(a,b]=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F$ is increasing?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ an increasing function. Why is there a unique measure $\mu$ s.t. $$\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a) \ \ ?$$

Indeed, I could imagine an other measure $\nu$ s.t. $$\nu((a,b])=\mu((a,b]),$$
for all $a,b$ s.t. $a<b$, but for a more exotic measurable set $A$, we could have $\mu(A)\neq \nu(A)$.

Comment: Is $\mu$ a measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R$? Depending on the $\sigma$-algebra you are working on, it is possible that $]a,b]$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not that there is a unique measure, but rather that there is a unique Borel measure. This can be proved directly using [Caratheodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) -- basically, sticking to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra rules out the more complicated measurable sets you might be imagining.

(It should maybe be also mentioned that $F$ also needs to be right-continuous to generate the pre-measure that Caratheodory turns into a  Borel measure. This wasn't stated in your question but is a typical assumption, especially in the context of probability and turning CDFs into measures.)

For more info, you might look up [Stieltjes' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) -- the $\mu$ you mention is the measure that appears when integrating against a CDF in that context.